# Unexpected StopLoss order placed and triggered in R

Tags: r, quantstrat

sorry for causing potentially any inconvenience: I am cross posting from r-sig-finance as I have not received any input on below issue.

++++

Hi all,

I am testing a simple Bollinger-Breakout:

if Close > UpperBand Then Long

if Close < LowerbandBand Then Short

if Close Crosses MidBand Then Exit

Here is what happens:

- I am entering as expected a short position on closing below the lower band
- Immediately after entering the short position, in the order book I can see a stop loss limit order being created: BELOW the entry price of my short position
- Price drops further, stop loss is getting triggered and my short gets closed at the stop loss threshhold, but BELOW the entry price

I would expect:

a) the stop loss to be triggered created above my entry price of my short
b) and getting triggered when losing money and not when making. What am I doing wrong here?

I am not sure which parts of my code would help, and before flooding you with orderbook, transactions etc. I'll start with my signal and rules (below).
Your input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
add.indicator(strat.st, name = "BBands",
  arguments = list(HLC = quote(HLC(mktdata)), maType='SMA'), label='BBands')

add.signal(strat.st, name="sigCrossover",
  arguments=list(columns=c("Close","up"),relationship="gt"),
  label="Cl.gt.UpperBand")

add.signal(strat.st, name="sigCrossover",
  arguments=list(columns=c("Close","dn"),relationship="lt"),
  label="Cl.lt.LowerBand")

add.signal(strat.st, name="sigCrossover",
  arguments=list(columns=c("Close","mavg"),relationship="gt"),
  label="Cross.Mid.GT")

add.signal(strat.st, name="sigCrossover",
           arguments=list(columns=c("Close","mavg"),relationship="lt"),
           label="Cross.Mid.LT")

add.rule(strat.st, name='ruleSignal',
  arguments=list(sigcol="Cl.gt.UpperBand",sigval=TRUE, orderqty=1,
    ordertype='market', orderside=NULL, threshold=NULL, osFUN=osFixedDollar,
    orderset='ocolong'),
    type='enter',label="LE")

add.rule(strat.st, name='ruleSignal',
  arguments=list(sigcol="Cl.lt.LowerBand",sigval=TRUE, orderqty= -1,
    ordertype='market', orderside=NULL, threshold=NULL, osFUN=osFixedDollar,
    orderset='ocoshort'),
  type='enter',label="SE")

add.rule(strat.st, name='ruleSignal',
  arguments=list(sigcol="Cross.Mid.GT",sigval=TRUE, orderqty= 'all',
    ordertype='market', orderside=NULL, threshold=NULL),
  type='exit', label="midCrossGT")

add.rule(strat.st, name='ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(sigcol="Cross.Mid.LT",sigval=TRUE, orderqty= 'all',
                        ordertype='market', orderside=NULL, threshold=NULL),
         type='exit', label="midCrossLT")

add.rule(strat.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(sigcol='Cl.gt.UpperBand' , sigval=TRUE,
                        replace=FALSE,
                        orderside=NULL,
                        ordertype='limit',
                        tmult=TRUE,
                        threshold=quote(.stoploss),
                        orderqty='all',
                        orderset='ocolong'
         ),
         type='chain', parent='LE',
         label='StopLossLONG',
         enabled=FALSE
)

add.rule(strat.st, name = 'ruleSignal',
         arguments=list(sigcol='Cl.lt.LowerBand' , sigval=TRUE,
                        replace=FALSE,
                        orderside=NULL,
                        ordertype='limit',
                        tmult=TRUE,
                        threshold=quote(.stoploss),
                        orderqty='all',
                        orderset='ocoshort'
         ),
         type='chain', parent='SE',
         label='StopLossSHORT',
         enabled=FALSE
)
```

Comment: You should probably add what package you have those functions in. `quantmod` I assume? And also what data you are using.

Comment: package: Quantsrat and run on historical tic data (OHLC in different resolutions: hourly, daily etc)

Comment: Tag with quanstrat too

Comment: @Peter Sounds like you want to be using ordertype = 'stoplimit' and you want to correctly set the orderside to "long" or "short" in your arguments to ruleSignal.